# Entity Framework Core don't generate Group By SQL instruction?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to get 3 lists:

- all advertisers (distinct);
- all categories (distinct);
- all package ids (distinct).

I have the following LINQ:

```
var filtersData = from push in _pushRepository.Pushes.Select(x =>  new
                {
                    x.Advertiser,
                    x.Category,
                    x.PackageId
                })
                group push by new
                {
                    push.Advertiser,
                    push.Category,
                    push.PackageId

                }
                into gr
                select  new
                {
                    advertisers = gr.Select(x => x.Advertiser).Distinct(),
                    categories = gr.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct(),                    
                    appIds = gr.Select(x => x.PackageId).Distinct()
                };
```

It's pretty close to this SQL query:

```
        SELECT x."Advertiser", x."Category", x."PackageId"
FROM "Pushes" AS x
group by  x."Advertiser", x."Category", x."PackageId"
```

But without `distinct`.

And I have switched on query logging for `npgsql`. It was surprise for me, but the LINQ instruction don't generate `Group by`. Please, see console debug output:

[image]

Is it correct behavior and EF Core will make grouping with the help of inner mechanisms or there is my mistake in the LINQ?

P.S. I use .NET Core 2.2

Comment: I can get 3 lists per 3 requests, but I would like per one))

Comment: Yes, because SQL can't do this. Only something like `gr.Count()` (or other aggregate functions) has a SQL equivalent. That's exactly what EF core 3 is struggling with now. They abandoned client-side evaluation in EF core 3 (kudos), but supporting all LINQ `GroupBy` features will *always* require client-side evaluation. Even EF6 does that (while it's said to have no CSE at all).

Comment: Technically this is still "wrong" (or "sub-optimal" rather) because it decides by itself to shift the burden of initially grouping the rows to the client. The initial `GROUP BY` / `DISTINCT` could be done by the database (consider the case of 100K rows, each with the same value for all three columns -- the client would only need to perform the distinct on the single row returned by the DB). Of course this could easily be forced with `Distinct().AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @gert-arnold wrote in the comment, your usage of GroupBy cannot be translated to SQL - an aggregate operator must be applied for that. Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby) to better understand which cases can be translated by EF Core.

You can still perform the GroupBy in the client side by inserting an AsEnumerable before the GroupBy operator.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I don't understand, but it's impossible to aggregate some data in a List? I mean some data I will group but the next half of data (that I will not group) I would like to pass in list. This is not a sum, not an avg, but pass in a List as the result of aggregation. It would be very convenient!

Comment: SQL simply doesn't support that. You can still pull in all the results and group them into lists on the client as I wrote above.